# in .htaccess forward some requests to index and some to different subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am debugging legacy `Codeigniter` application `V2.3.1` and I developled `api` using `Lumen` in another subfolder, I want to forward all the requests to the index.php as it is right now except URLs with specific patterns will be forwarded to the api folder.

Currently in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|data|stylesheet|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

URL: `http://app.test/abcd/xyz/lem` will go to `index.php`

I want to make this URL: `http://app.test/api/abcd/xyz/lem` go to `app/api/public`

the folder structure for the application:

```
App
- application
- api (my application)
- data
- system
- .htaccess
- index.php
```

Thanx,

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /app/
##external redirect for uri.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^api app/api/public [R=301,L]

##internal rewrite for uri here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|data|stylesheet|images|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` Ierror I cleared the cache but no luck

Comment: @YaBasha, could you please try my edited code once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: no it didn't work, I just put a simple html page in the `api` folder to test if its working

Comment: @YaBasha, ok I have 3questions here:1- do you want to serve all non-existing pages by index,php? 2- Do you have any other rules in your file? 3- When you hit html file that also should be served by index.php? Could you please confirm on these once, thank you.

Comment: thank you for your help, the api subfolder is just another Codeigniter application but newer version so I can create REST server but I moved it and put an index.html file to make sure that redirect is working, regarding your questions: 1- I want index.php in the parent folder to serve all the requests that don't include `api` segment 2- No there is not any rule the file as the one you edited in the code section 3- the html file is just a demo to test. the two applications are separated just the hostname combine them is this possiple or should i check for a subdomain.

Comment: @YaBasha, ok try removing `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^api app/api/public [R=301,L]` these 2 rules once and then save it in htaccess and try it once, let me know how it goes?

Comment: @YaBasha, Hi, could you please do let me know if my answer has helped you?